# Efficient map and filter combination vs stdlibs

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to write an efficient solution to a common map/filter paradigm. In Kotlin, you can write code that looks like this:

```
schedule.daysOfWeek.map { it.adjustInto(today) as LocalDate }
        .filterTo(datesOnSchedule) { it.isBefore(endDate) }
```

Generically, I'm applying a map, then filtering the mapped values based on a condition. However, an intermediate collection is created for this. This seems unnecessary. I wrote a little function that should do the same thing, but without the intermediate collection.

```
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.mapThenFilter(predicate: (R) -> Boolean, transform: (T) -> R) {
    mapThenFilter(ArrayList<R>(), predicate, transform)
}

inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>>
    Iterable<T>.mapThenFilter(collection: C, predicate: (R) -> Boolean, transform: (T) -> R): C {
for (element in this) {
    val mapped = transform(element)
    if(predicate(mapped)) {
        collection.add(mapped)
    }
   }
 return collection
}
```

However, IntelliJ is suggesting a stdlib replacement for my function that would make it look like:

```
    inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> 
Iterable<T>.mapThenFilter(collection: C, predicate: (R) -> Boolean, transform: (T) -> R): C {
    this.map { transform(it) }
        .filterTo(collection) { predicate(it) }
    return collection
}
```

Which turns my optimization straight back into the original code I wrote and re-introduces the inefficiency of creating multiple collections. Is there some optimization going on here that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no optimization; the IntelliJ IDEA suggestion is intended to show you the more idiomatic way to perform a certain operation and does not always preserve the performance of the original code. Obviously you know what you're doing, so you should either ignore the suggestion of the inspection or suppress it.